# Multiple assignments to variables on worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function which goes to a particular worksheet in a workbook and takes some data from there and returns it to the function. Here is the code:

```
Function nameOfFlow(jobSheet As String, jobName As String) As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim curCell As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets(jobSheet)
    For curCell = 2 To ws.Rows.Count
        If ws.Cells(curCell, 2).Value = jobName Then
            nameOfFlow = ws.Cells(curCell, 2).Offset(0, 3).Value
        End If
    Next curCell
End Function
```

The thing is when this function is called only once then it works fine and functions as expected. But when for example it is called more than once in the same flow, then I get an error on the line where I assign the variable to the Worksheet. I am not really sure what is going wrong here. I get a `Subscript out of Range` error. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If this function is in your Personal.xlsb you may get this error if the current ActiveBook is not the one you expect

Comment: And you should avoid this line of code : For curCell = 2 To ws.Rows.Count.  You will iterate through all rows of your WorkBook ...

Comment: Thank you Seb for your answer. I added a ThisWorkbook.Activate in the function that calls this function and it worked! Now, I am not so experienced with VBA but, can you please let me know if it is possible to iterate only through those rows that have some cells that have values inside them? I know this is not related to this question. But, it would be great if you could let me know!

Comment: I will formulate an Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this function is in your Personal.xlsb you may get this error if the current ActiveBook is not the one you expect.  Make sure the Active Workbook is the one containing the WorkSheet 'jobSheet' OR pass ws as a parameter to your 'nameOfFlow' function.

You should avoid this line of code :

```
For curCell = 2 To ws.Rows.Count
```

It will cause you macro to iterate through ALL rows of your WorkBook.

You can correct that that way :

```
For curCell = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    If ws.Cells(curCell, 1).Value = jobName Then
        nameOfFlow = ws.Cells(curCell, 2).Offset(0, 3).Value
    End If
Next curCell
```